# import in python file has imported file

Tags: python

I have python project like

```
/project
|__main.py
|__/graph 
|____grapher.py
|____object_map_genaration.py
```

- In grapher: `import object_map_genaration`
- In main: `import grapher`

But I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_map_genaration'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add an init here:

```
/project/
|__/main.py
|__/graph/
|____/__init__.py
|____/grapher.py
|____/object_map_genaration.py
```

Then in grapher.py:

```
from . import object_map_genaration
```

And in main.py:

```
from graph import grapher
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `from grapher import object_map_genaration` not just `import object_map_genaration`, since imports are relative to the root of the main file.